# White noise spots on our IP Camera, is it faulty?

Tags: noise, camera

Can anyone help us solve what could cause white noise spots on the images from our IP camera? There is only one light source - the window above door. Is the camera faulty?

We keep getting notifications and seeing camera ghosts is not very helpful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks and apologies if this is not the right forum for this post, I didn’t find a “kinda supernatural smart camera sightings” one...

Comment: It could be a flying insect. With such a wide angle lens, objects close to the lens will appear excessively larger than background objects.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be some insect that is drawn to the light. Due to the closeness to the camera, it is out of focus and appears that big.

Answer (score 4):

The light source seems to be in the left of the image, close to the camera.
Since all images were taken at night I belive it could be an insect very close to light source and camera.
Like a moth or something like that.